How to remove the black area from youtube_player_flutter and show the video on full view?
I am using youtube_player_flutter package for displaying YouTube videos in my app but the problem I am facing is that there is a black area visible above and below of the video:

How I can remove the black area and make sure the video takes whole container space?
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:auctions/Models/videosModel.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class VideoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final double aspectRatio;
  final List<VideosData>? data;
  final bool showSingleVideo;
  final String singleVideoLink;

  const VideoCard({
    Key? key,
    this.index = 0,
    this.data,
    this.aspectRatio = 1.19,
    this.showSingleVideo = false,
    this.singleVideoLink = "",
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoCard> createState() => _VideoCardState();
}

class _VideoCardState extends State<VideoCard> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  late ValueNotifier<PlayerState> _playerStateNotifier;

  late String? videoId;
  bool isPlayerInitialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    videoId = widget.showSingleVideo
        ? YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.singleVideoLink)
        : YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(
            widget.data![widget.index].youtubeVideoLink);

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: videoId ?? "",
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          mute: false,
          autoPlay: false,
          disableDragSeek: true,
          loop: false,
          isLive: false,
          forceHD: false,
          enableCaption: true,
        ),
      );

      _playerStateNotifier =
          ValueNotifier<PlayerState>(_controller.value.playerState);
      _controller.addListener(_listener);
      setState(() {
        isPlayerInitialized = true;
      });
    });
  }

  void _listener() {
    _playerStateNotifier.value = _controller.value.playerState;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (isPlayerInitialized) {
      _controller.removeListener(_listener);
      _controller.dispose();
      _playerStateNotifier.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          if (!isPlayerInitialized)
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: widget.aspectRatio,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (isPlayerInitialized)
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: widget.aspectRatio,
              child: YoutubePlayerBuilder(
                onExitFullScreen: () {
                  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
                      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
                },
                player: YoutubePlayer(
                  width: Platform.isAndroid ? 310 : 330,
                  controller: _controller,
                  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                  progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  bottomActions: const [
                    CurrentPosition(),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    RemainingDuration(),
                  ],
                ),
                builder: (context, player) {
                  return player;
                },
              ),
            ),
          // Show loading indicator during buffering
          if (isPlayerInitialized)
            ValueListenableBuilder<PlayerState>(
              valueListenable: _playerStateNotifier,
              builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                if (playerState == PlayerState.buffering) {
                  return Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

here is the package implementation class please let me know how i can made modifications to get the desire behivour
